# finding value in nested jquery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I cant get that to work:

My json

```
[{"myicons":[{"icon":[{"rel":"1","id":"icon1","class":"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark1"}]},{"icon":[{"rel":"2","id":"icon2","class":"bookmark desktop-icon ui-draggable","title":"bookmark2"}]}]}]
```

My jquery each function finds the 2 icons but i cant seem to get the values... it keeps saying undefined.

```
var myicons = data[0].myicons;
            $.each(myicons, function() {

                var iconid = this.id;
                alert(iconid);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is full of array. i,e. `data`, `myicons` and even `icon`

```
$.each(data, function () {
    var myicons = this.myicons;
    $.each(myicons, function () {
        var iconid = this.icon[0].id;
        alert(iconid);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ttw78/)

I strongly suggest you to simplify yous JSON object

Comment: @MartijnMichel, As I have said your JSON is full of array. See formatted JSON object you will understand. If you have problem ping me

Comment: hmm actually when i remove the first each it still works. thanks for helping me out!

Comment: ah ok,, because then each icon is an object inside the array icons. thanks!

Comment: @MartijnMichel, You got it mate

Comment: Thanks i changed my json file and yes much easier to find the values! ;)